# Change from polygon to multipolygon in PostGres

Tags: qgis, postgresql

Can somebody describe please how to do the transformation from polygon to multipolygon in the PostGres DB, is not possible for me to save my edited data.

All data loaded just need to do some editing upon my polygons.

Answer (score 1):

If you need transform from Polygon to Multipolygon you can use st_multi function.

http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Multi.html

Comment: my data in db is already multipolygon my problem is qgis is trying to save data as polygon and here appers the problem..